# Pyspark - TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when calculating mean using reduceByKey

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

my "asdasd.csv" file has the following structure.

```
 Index,Arrival_Time,Creation_Time,x,y,z,User,Model,Device,gt
0,1424696633908,1424696631913248572,-5.958191,0.6880646,8.135345,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
1,1424696633909,1424696631918283972,-5.95224,0.6702118,8.136536,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
2,1424696633918,1424696631923288855,-5.9950867,0.6535491999999999,8.204376,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
3,1424696633919,1424696631928385290,-5.9427185,0.6761626999999999,8.128204,a,nexus4,nexus4_1,stand
```

Ok, I get the following {key,value} tuple to operate with it.

```
#                                 x           y        z
[(('a', 'nexus4', 'stand'), ((-5.958191, 0.6880646, 8.135345)))]
#           part A (key)               part B (value)
```

My code for calculating the mean is the following, I have to calculate the mean from each column, X, Y Z for each Key.

```
rdd_ori = sc.textFile("asdasd.csv") \
        .map(lambda x: ((x.split(",")[6], x.split(",")[7], x.split(",")[9]),(float(x.split(",")[3]),float(x.split(",")[4]),float(x.split(",")[5]))))

meanRDD = rdd_ori.mapValues(lambda x: (x,1)) \
            .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a[0][0] + b[0][0], a[0][1] + b[0][1], a[0][2] + b[0][2], a[1] + b[1]))\
            .mapValues(lambda a : (a[0]/a[3], a[1]/a[3],a[2]/a[3]))
```

My problem I that I tried that code and it works fine on other PC with the same MV I'm using for developing it (PySpark Py3)

Here is an example, that this code is correct:

[image]

But I don't know why I'm getting this error, important part is in **Strong**.

> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
> >     last)  in ()
> >           9 #sum_1 = count_.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0][0]+y[0][0],x[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3lz.jpg)+y[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3lz.jpg),x[0][2]+y[0][2]))
> >          10 
> >     ---> 11 print(meanRDD.take(1))
>
> /opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self, num)    1341
>   1342             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned +
>   numPartsToTry, totalParts))
>   -> 1343             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)    1344     1345             items += res
>
> /opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/context.py in runJob(self, rdd,
>   partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
>       990         # SparkContext#runJob.
>       991         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
>   --> 992         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
>       993         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
>       994
>
> /opt/spark/current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1131         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1132         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1134     1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /opt/spark/current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       320             else:
>       321                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 127.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 127.0 (TID 102, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/opt/spark/current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line
>   177, in main
>       process()   File "/opt/spark/current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line
>   172, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File "/opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2423, in
>   pipeline_func
>       return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "/opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2423, in
>   pipeline_func
>       return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))   File "/opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 346, in func
>       return f(iterator)   File "/opt/spark/current/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1842, in
>   combineLocally
>       merger.mergeValues(iterator)   File "/opt/spark/current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line
>   238, in mergeValues
>       **d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)   File "", line 3, in  TypeError:
>   'float' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: is there any reason you're not using dataframes for this?

Comment: Ramesh Maharjan - could you help with my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831826/typeerror-float-object-is-not-subscriptable-from-machine-learning-with-python please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Heres how `reduceByKey` works. I am taking your example for illustration i.e. with following data that you pass to `reduceByKey`**

```
#                                 x           y        z
[(('a', 'nexus4', 'stand'), ((-5.958191, 0.6880646, 8.135345), 1))]
#           part A (key)               part B (value)       counter
```

Let me go step by step

After performing the following `mapValues` function

```
rdd_ori.mapValues(lambda x: (x,1))
```

the *rdd data* will look as

```
((u'a', u'nexus4', u'stand'), ((-5.9427185, 0.6761626999999999, 8.128204), 1))
((u'a', u'nexus4', u'stand'), ((-5.958191, 0.6880646, 8.135345), 1))
((u'a', u'nexus4', u'stand'), ((-5.95224, 0.6702118, 8.136536), 1))
((u'a', u'nexus4', u'stand'), ((-5.9950867, 0.6535491999999999, 8.204376), 1))
```

So when `reduceByKey` is invoked as

```
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a[0][0] + b[0][0], a[0][1] + b[0][1], a[0][2] + b[0][2], a[1] + b[1]))
```

And **all the rows with same key are grouped and values are passed to the `lambda` function of `reducyByKey`**.

Since in your case, *all the keys are same*, the values are passed to `a` and `b` variables in the following iterations.

In first iteration, `a` is `((-5.9427185, 0.6761626999999999, 8.128204), 1)` and `b` is `((-5.958191, 0.6880646, 8.135345), 1)` so the calculation part `(a[0][0] + b[0][0], a[0][1] + b[0][1], a[0][2] + b[0][2], a[1] + b[1])` is correct and passes.

In second iteration, `a` is the output of `(a[0][0] + b[0][0], a[0][1] + b[0][1], a[0][2] + b[0][2], a[1] + b[1])` which is `(-11.910430999999999, 1.3582764, 16.271881, 2)`

**So if you look at the format of the data there is no such `a[0][0]` in `a`. You can just get `a[0]`, `a[1]` .. and so on. So thats the issue. And thats what the error message is suggesting too**.

> > TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

**The solution to this is to format the data so that you can access `a` as `a[0][0]` which can be done if you format your `reduceByKey` of the following format.**

```
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: ((a[0][0] + b[0][0], a[0][1] + b[0][1], a[0][2] + b[0][2]), a[1] + b[1]))
```

But that would trouble your last `mapValues` function

```
.mapValues(lambda a : (a[0]/a[3], a[1]/a[3],a[2]/a[3]))
```

as your values, **i.e. `a` in lambda function**, are of `((-23.848236199999995, 2.6879882999999998, 32.604461), 4)` so `a[0]` means `(-23.848236199999995, 2.6879882999999998, 32.604461)` and `a[1]` means `4` and there aren't any more so you will encounter

> > IndexError: tuple index out of range

So your last `mapValues` should be

```
.mapValues(lambda a : (a[0][0]/a[1], a[0][1]/a[1],a[0][2]/a[1]))
```

**So overall, following code should work for you**

```
rdd_ori = sc.textFile("asdasd.csv") \
    .map(lambda x: ((x.split(",")[6], x.split(",")[7], x.split(",")[9]),(float(x.split(",")[3]),float(x.split(",")[4]),float(x.split(",")[5]))))

meanRDD = rdd_ori.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: ((a[0][0] + b[0][0], a[0][1] + b[0][1], a[0][2] + b[0][2]), a[1] + b[1]))\
    .mapValues(lambda a : (a[0][0]/a[1], a[0][1]/a[1],a[0][2]/a[1]))
```

I hope I have explained it well enough.