# Subtract tuple element to other tuple - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to using spark and python

I have the following tuple

```
#Money in each account
[(key), {(4.32,32.32,23.3),(3.23,32.2,21.3)}]
```

What I have to do, is to subtract from each element for example (4.32,32.32,23.3) the mean corresponding to each account, to 4.32 - 3.23, to 32.32 - 32.32 ...

My idea is to do the following.

```
subtract = myRDD.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: ((x[0][0]-y[1][0]), (x[0][1]-y[1][1]), (x[0][2]-y[1][2])))
```

But I don't know how can I enter the index properly.

My input file has the following structure.

```
Index,Person,Account1,Account2,Account3
0,Serge,5.958191,0.6880646,8.135345
```

Then I calculate the mean for each row, so for example to all the Keys with name Serge I have the following data tuple.

```
{('Serge'),((5.958191,0.6880646,8.135345),(3.23,32.2,21.3))}
```

Now what I want is to subtract to each element its mean...

So for example in this case, I want a tuple with the following structure.

```
{('Serge'),((5.958191-3.23,0.6880646-32.2,8.135345-21.3, 10))}
```

My code;

```
data = sc.textFile("myFile.csv")

data1 = data.map(lambda x: ((x.split(",")[1]),(x.split(",")[2],x.split(",")[3],x.split(",")[4]))

mean = data.mapValues( lambda x: (x,1) ) \
     .reduceByKey (lambda x , y: ((x[0][0] + y[0][0], x[0][1] + y[0][1], x[0][2] + y[0][2]), x[1] + y[1])).mapValues (lambda a: (a[0][0]/a[1],a[0][1]/a[1],a[0][2]/a[1], a[1]))

data2 = mean.join(data1)
```

**Last a[1] from mapValues is to get my items count.**

Comment: can we get some sample lines of your input lines ?

Comment: Ofc, one second I update my first coment

Comment: Just Updated the post

Comment: You won't need reduceByKey in my thought but I would need to confirm so can you also update on how you get the means ? can you specify how did you reach to get `{('Serge'),((5.958191,0.6880646,8.135345),(3.23,32.2,21.3))}`?

Comment: Just Updated the post

Comment: meanwhile I figure out this question you can take a look at my other answer similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706

Comment: Ok, but which is the correct index to access to it?

Comment: yes sorry, I forgive my Join part, where I join my first RDD which each mean and count

Comment: @J Joe I have answered as much as I understood from your question please check below

Answer (score 0):

If you have *mean rdd* which you get after `reduceByKey` as

```
(u'Serge', (-5.962059049999999, 0.6719970749999999, 8.15111525))
```

and *data1 rdd* which you get after reading a fresh file

```
(u'Serge', (3.23, 32.2, 21.3))
```

and you `join` them

```
data2 = mean.join(data1)
```

so that you have

```
(u'Serge', ((-5.962059049999999, 0.6719970749999999, 8.15111525), (3.23, 32.2, 21.3)))
```

> > Now what I want is to subtract to each element its mean...
> >     So for example in this case, I want a tuple with the following structure.
> >     {('Serge'),((5.958191-3.23,0.6880646-32.2,8.135345-21.3, 10))}

I don't know where that `10` is coming from but *to subtract you can simply use map function* as

```
data2.map(lambda x: ((x[0]), (x[1][0][0] - x[1][1][0], x[1][0][1] - x[1][1][1], x[1][0][2] - x[1][1][2])))
```

so the final result would be

```
('Serge', (-9.19205905, -31.528002925000003, -13.14888475))
```

I hope the answer is helpful