# How to convert var to List?

Tags: scala

How to convert one var to two var List?

Below is my input variable:

```
val input="[level:1,var1:name,var2:id][level:1,var1:name1,var2:id1][level:2,var1:add1,var2:city]"
```

I want my result should be:

```
  val first= List(List("name","name1"),List("add1"))
  val second= List(List("id","id1"),List("city"))
```

Comment: thats not a valid json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `input` is **not a valid json**

```
val input="[level:1,var1:name,var2:id][level:1,var1:name1,var2:id1][level:2,var1:add1,var2:city]"
```

**You have to make it *valid json RDD*** ( as you are going to use apache spark)

```
val validJsonRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(input)).flatMap(x => x.replace(",", "\",\"").replace(":", "\":\"").replace("[", "{\"").replace("]", "\"}").replace("}{", "}&{").split("&"))
```

Once you have *valid json rdd, you can easily convert that to `dataframe`* and *then apply the logic you have*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.read.json(validJsonRdd)
  .groupBy("level")
  .agg(collect_list("var1").as("var1"), collect_list("var2").as("var2"))
  .select(collect_list("var1").as("var1"), collect_list("var2").as("var2"))
```

You *should get desired output in `dataframe`* as

```
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|var1                                            |var2                                        |
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|[WrappedArray(name1, name2), WrappedArray(add1)]|[WrappedArray(id1, id2), WrappedArray(city)]|
+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

And you can *convert the array to list if required*

To get the values as in the question, you can do the following

```
val rdd = df.collect().map(row => (row(0).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]], row(1).asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]]))

val first = rdd(0)._1.map(x => x.toList).toList
//first: List[List[String]] = List(List(name1, name2), List(add1))

val second = rdd(0)._2.map(x => x.toList).toList
//second: List[List[String]] = List(List(id1, id2), List(city))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot. i need to assign the column var1 as another variable. from var1 column each row as a list like:val first= List(List("name","name1"),List("add1"))

Comment: Ranjan Thanks for the update, your output showing everything in one variable [WrappedArray(name1, name2), WrappedArray(id1, id2)] but i wanted the output as List(List(name1, name2),List(add1)) in one variable and next List(List(id1, id2),List(city))in one more variable.

Comment: "first: Array[(List[String], List[String])] = Array((List(name1, name2),List(id1, id2)))"  is the output you are showing but i need it as "List(List(name1, name2),List(add1))" ... My concern is not only to convert the array as to list but the content also please check i want the entire column data in one variable. you are showing the entire row data in one variable.... kindly help :(  :( :( ...

Comment: Super thanks a lot its working Hurreyyyyy... You are my savior thanks a lot........... :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

`reduceByKey` is the important function to achieve your required output. More explaination on [step by step reduceByKey explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706)

You can do the following

```
val input="[level:1,var1:name1,var2:id1][level:1,var1:name2,var2:id2][level:2,var1:add1,var2:city]"
val groupedrdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(input)).flatMap(_.split("]\\[").map(x => {
  val values = x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",").map(y => y.split(":")(1))
  (values(0), (List(values(1)), List(values(2))))
})).reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 ::: y._1, x._2 ::: y._2))


val first = groupedrdd.map(x => x._2._1).collect().toList
//first: List[List[String]] = List(List(add1), List(name1, name2))
val second = groupedrdd.map(x => x._2._2).collect().toList
//second: List[List[String]] = List(List(city), List(id1, id2))
```