# Counting occurrences of key while keeping several values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm having some trouble counting the number of occurrences of a key, while also keeping several values.

Usually I will just do:

```
val a = file1.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

which gives the number of occurrences for each key.

However, I also want to keep the values for each occurrence of a key, at the same time as counting the number of occurrences of the key. Something like this:

```
val a = file1.map(x => (x(1), (x(2), 1)).reduceByKey{case (x,y) => (x._1, y._1, x._2+y._2)}
```

For example: if the key `x(1)` is a country and `x(2)` is a city, I want to keep all the cities in a country, as well as knowing how many cities there are in a country.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example with input and expected output. The answers seem to solve slightly different variations of the same unclear problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated and redundant to keep the count of the cities together with its list. You can just collect all the cities, and add the size at the end:

It is of course easier if you use the dataframe interface (assuming a dataframe `(key:Int, city:String)`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ functions => f}
import spark.implicits._
df.groupBy($"key").
   agg(f.collect_set($"city").as("cities")).
   withColumn("ncities", f.size($"cities"))
```

but you can do something similar with raw rdd (I am assuming in input tuples of `(id,city)` )

```
rdd.map{ x => (x(0),Set(x(1)))}.
   reduceByKey{ case(x,y) => x ++ y }.
   map { case(x,y:Set[_]) => (x,y, y.size)}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would recommend using a dataframe instead of a RDD, and use the `groupBy` and `agg` methods.

You can easily convert an RDD to a dataframe using the `toDF` function, just make sure you import implicits first. Example assuming the RDD has two columns:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val df = rdd.toDF("country", "city")
```

Then use the `groupBy` and aggregate the values you want.

```
df.groupBy("country").agg(collect_set($"city").as("cities"), count($"city").as("count"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go with `dataframes` as well as `dataframes` are *optimized and easy to use* than `rdds`.

But if you want to learn about `reduceByKey` functionality (i.e. *keeping other information as you said city information*) then you can do something like below

Lets say you have a `rdd` as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("country1", "city1"),
  ("country1", "city2"),
  ("country1", "city3"),
  ("country1", "city3"),
  ("country2", "city1"),
  ("country2", "city2")
))
```

Your tried `reducyByKey` would need some modification as

```
rdd.map(x => (x._1, (Set(x._2), 1)))  //I have used Set to get distinct cities (you can use list or arrays or any other collection
  .reduceByKey((x,y)=> (x._1 ++ y._1, x._2 + y._2))  //cities are also summed and counts are also summed
```

which should give you

```
(country2,(Set(city1, city2),2))
(country1,(Set(city1, city2, city3),4))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**If you want to learn reduceByKey in detail you can check my [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706)**